# Arduino uno with radio nrf24l01 is no avaliable

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have two Arduino UNO and two NRF24L01. One works as a transmitter and the second as a receiver. Here is the code for the receiver:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);

const byte rxAddr[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  while (!Serial)
    ;
  Serial.begin(57600);

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, rxAddr);
  radio.startListening();  
}

void loop()
{
Serial.println("receiver - loop");

  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));

    Serial.println(text);

    Serial.println("receiver - available");
  } else {
    Serial.println("receiver - no available");
  }
}
```

NRF24L01 is connected to the arduino:

- VCC - 3,3V
- GND - GND
- CE - 7
- CSN - 8
- MOSI - 11
- MISO - 12
- SCK - 13

My problem is weird. After opening a serial monitor the on output is "receiver - no available". But when I disconnect NRF24L01 from the arduino the on output is: "receiver - available". I tried changing the RF module but the result is same. I don't understand why the receiver is available if the RF module is not connected? Where is the problem? Do I have wrong code?

Comment: With the receiver module disconnected, is anything actually read out with `radio.read()`?  i.e. Do you see anything printed other than "receiver - available"?

Comment: I don´t know why but now it works. I think I have bad NRF24L01 modules. First works well as transmitter and receiver. Second and third work only as transmitters and they don´t work as receivers. Fourth doesn't work at all.